# Unicode not being written to html file python

Tags: python, html, unicode, utf-8, ascii

So I parse a xml file for tags with attributes using minidom. My attribute of my python obj that holds the name of this attribute called "name", when i debug it, holds this value "RTÉ News". The problem is I have a helper object I created to construct a html table for me for a report. Even this when I debug it, holds the value in memory of "RTÉ News" in the string value I return to construct the cell "RTÉ News" but when I use this code;

```
with codecs.open(Resources.REPORT, "w", "utf-8") as f:
    reportHelper = ReportsHelper()
    print reportHelper.createResultHTMLReportUnicodeHandled()
    f.write(reportHelper.createHTMLReportUnicodeHandled())
    f.close()
```

Result:

"RTÃ‰ News" in my html report.

Any ideas, I'm a java head, only had to pick up python for a week to prove something. Cheers guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct IMO. Why using

```
with codecs.open(Resources.REPORT, "w", "utf-8") as f:
```

instead of

```
with open(Resources.REPORT, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

?

If you open your HTML file within a browser, have you tried manually setting the encoding ? In Firefox 19 : view -> Characters Encoding -> UTF-8

I suppose your file is correctly encoded but your HTML viewer doesn't detect the encoding correctly.